# normal subgroup, diagonal embedding.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Suppose that $A$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and $A$ is abelian. Let $i:A\rightarrow A\times G$ a morphism of groups given by $a\mapsto (a,a)$. Is is clear that $i(A)$ is a normal subgroup of $A\times G$ ?

Comment: Since $G$ acts trivially on the first $A$ factor, for this to work it would have to act trivially on the second factor too.  That means you would need $A$ central.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not true. Take e.g. $A = C_3$, the cyclic group of order three, viewed as the set of rotations inside $G = D_6$, the symmetry group of the triangle.

It is, however, true that $i(A)$ is normal if and only if $i(A)$ is central, if and only if $A$ is central.